# Bind input value to ng-click button (send value as parameter)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-model

I'm trying to bind the value from an input field to the parameter of my method on ng-click. Here's what I got, but it doesn't work, and I am not too sure if it's possible to do it this way?:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{post.PostId}}" />
<button ng-click="getById(post.PostId)"></button>
<h1>{{post.Title}}</h1>


$scope.getById = function (id) {
        console.log(id);
        return $http.get('/api/Post/' + id);
    }
```

Comment: what problem you are getting now after changing code to @JDTLH9 suggestion?

Comment: Well the problem is that the title of  the post isn't appearing at all in the `h1` tag

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use `ng-model` directive for your input element.

**Markup**

```
 <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="post.PostId" />
 <button ng-click="getById(post.PostId)"></button>
 <h1>{{post.Title}}</h1>
```

This will take care of 2-way model binding to your property `post.PostId`. Your `ng-click` directive will pick up the correct value entered in input element.

See my working [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vkVquAL3Jl3gGdV5iZxW) :)

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to work, but I added more code to the original post so that you can see the getById :)

Comment: @btmach it should work as you wanted. Please see the link to the Plunk in my edited answer.